# UTF-8 character in Url change when after copy it from firefox

Tags: javascript, php, firefox, curl, libcurl

a website in Russian when I go to the website on firefox and copy it again it changed to strange chars what I submit in firefox is

```
?field_searchindex_value=английский&send=Применить&page=0
```

when I go to the page info or copy the full link again from firefox I go this

```
?field_searchindex_value=%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9&send=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C&page=0
```

I ask about what this strange chars and how to convert this name in rusian

```
английский
```

to this characters

```
%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9
```

because when I use the first link with Russian in my windows cmd because I use curl binary to download the website data it show me `?????`
but when I use the strange characters copied from firefox it works 
so what I should do to convert my Russian words to this link I need help because I don't know where to search about this so any help or explain I will appreciate this 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function in browser console.

To open console in Chrome press `F12`, then `Esc` if you don't see it.

Firefox shortcut `Ctrl + Shift + I`

```
encodeURIComponent( 'английский' );
//"%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9"
```

Answer (score 1):

For switching windows command line to displaying Unicode you should run `chcp 65001`
In previous answer you saw the JS `encodeURIComponent( 'английский' );` or PHP `urlencode( 'английский' )` encodes your URL